# cannot start debugging because no launch configuration has been provided

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I was doing C programming and then this happened to the VS code all of sudden, can anyone help me how to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: I've never used VS code but did you check these? : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations

Comment: Open the folder for your C program from VS Code. Then from the Run menu, click "Add Configuration" to get a default configuration.